# Challenging while upgrading jfrog artifactory from 6.9 to 7.71 and mounting the local existing stored artifactories into gcs bucket

Tags: artifactory, artifacts, jfrog-cli, jfrog-mission-control

H All,
I am using jfrog artifactory OSS version 6.9.6. i want it to upgrade to 7.71 which i think latest.
But facing lots of issues while upgrading as well as migrating to the GCS bucket.
**Please note,** Everyting i have performed in same system, and when Issue1,Issue2 didn't get me to the answer i performed Issue3. Also, i have followed jfrog artifactory official document as well, but it didn't help me anyway.

**Issue1:-** While trying to inspect that which jfrog artifactory service is using which directory using `pwdx` command, that is giving me the output as /, which is unknown. Means it doesn't give me any output like which artifact directory it is running from.

**Issue2:-** While trying to stop jfrog artifactory service using example `systemctl stop artifactory.service` still it keeps on running in ui. Means service is not stopping.

**Issue3:-** I downloaded the updated version artifactory OSS 7.71 and installed in the same system, and bingo my artifactory upgraded to 7.71. But when i try to stop upgraded version service , that also is not stopping anyway. But still it keeps on running and shows this error. please note, my jfrog ui still up an running
[image: Refer to the below screenshot for upgraded version 7.71]

**Issue4:-** While mounting using gcsfuse command to my local directory using below command `gcsfuse --only-dir backup-daily/current/repositories xxxbucket_Namexxx "/opt/artifactory-oss-7.71.10/var/backup/artifactory/backup-daily/current/repositories"`, i already have copied few of the existing artifacts into gcs bucket, those files doesn't appear in local not even to the UI.

**Issue5:-** I want to keep the same user and their details in upgraded version 7.71 who were available in previous version 6.61. Is there any configurations files which i can copy or migrate?

Any info or lead or help appreciated in order to resolve it.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: how exactly did you upgrade Artifactory? Please note that you cannot upgrade directly from 6.9 to 7.71, you must upgrade first to 6.10.
Upgrade should not impact the number of artifacts or any user details appearing in your Artifactory as they are being saved in the DB, unless there is an issue connecting to the correct DB.
You can check this in the artifactory-service.log.
As for service not stopping issue, it might be impacted from several processes of Java running (did you try to kill all of them?) The script being executed usually is the artifactoryManage.sh

Comment: @shaibz Thanks for your response. I downloaded 7.71 zip file and then followed the steps to install. You can assume it like a fresh installation of 7.71 on the system.
Answer to the second, Yes i have tried killing all the process and automatically new java process comes up.

Comment: Next, i have tried stopping the artifactory version 6.9 using ./artifactoryManage.sh stop and with lots of information, at the ends it throws error like below

```+++ dirname ./artifactoryManage.sh
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ artBinDir=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin
+ ARTIFACTORY_PID=
+ artDefaultFile=/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default
.
.
.
+ SHUTDOWN_PORT=1
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' 30 -lt 30 ']'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'ERROR: Artifactory Tomcat did not stop'
ERROR: Artifactory Tomcat did not stop```

Comment: I think it would be best you contact Jfrog Support to handle this sort of question. There are too many variables to handle in Stack overflow.

Comment: @David Livshin Reverse has been suggested by jfrog support, to reach out o the community . :)