# Mount jfrog artifactory with gcs bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, artifactory, artifact, mount-point, gcsfuse

I have a requirement of mounting local stored jfrog artifactory OSS into gcs bucket. For that i have tried below in binarystore.xml file, But my ui keeps on running at starting window. It doesn't land to the starting page.

```
<config version="2">
    <chain template="cluster-google-storage-v2"/>
    <provider id="google-storage-v2" type="google-storage-v2">
        <endpoint>commondatastorage.googleapis.com</endpoint>
        <bucketName><BUCKET NAME></bucketName>
    </provider>
</config>
```

Please note
i have already copied all the local artifacts which were stored over the gcp vm, and now i want my artifacts to be used either read or write to gcs bucket.

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try adding this [testConnection](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/google-storage-binary-provider-native-client-template#:~:text=to%20be%20created.-,testConnection,-Default%3A%20true) parameter it will 

verify that the connection to the cloud storage provider is fully functional.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Not sure where to add this param, as its by default set as True. Is it like in the above confi i should give it as 
< testConnection >True</testConnection >
Also please confirm if possible, GCS can be mount with jfrog OSS ?
Thanks

Comment: Seems it is possible GCS can be mounted with JFrog OSS using Cloud Storage Fuse.Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138313/challenging-while-upgrading-jfrog-artifactory-from-6-9-to-7-71-and-mounting-the) which might help

Answer (score 0):

GCP Cloud storage requires Pro, Enterprise X, or an Enterprise+ license.

It is documented [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/google-cloud-storage).